# Can Matlab write a macro in an Excel file via ActiveX?

Tags: vba, matlab, excel, activex

There are several posts and instructions how to run Excel macros with Matlab via ActiveX. But is it possible to write such a macro with Matlab into an Excel file?

Background: I wrote a Matlab tool which exports data into Excel files. These Excel files should have a specific macro included which is dependend on the containing data.

Well there is an ugly workaround: I can create Excel templates with the specific macro already included. Then the respective template is copied and filled with the export data. But maybe there is a better and more flexible solution to this problem...

Comment: How are you writing to the files? Are you using Excel's object model? If so, then you can access the `Workbook`'s `VBProject` and it should be smooth sailing from there. If not, your current solution seems reasonable.

Comment: That said this question seems *too broad* to be a good fit for this site.

Comment: Your "ugly" workaround is often the most workable solution if you have multiple users: VBA access to alter the VBProject requires the "trust access to VBProject" setting, which is typically *not* enabled...

Comment: [trite comment] a better and more flexible solution is to avoid Excel completely and do all your data processing in MATLAB [/trite comment]

Comment: @TimWilliams ...and for very good reasons...

Comment: @Mat'sMug I add the data to the Excel files with `writeable(mydata,filepath)`
and start the macro with
`Excel = actxserver('Excel.Application')`
`Excel.Run('mymacro')`

To access the VBProject I disable the security settings mentioned by @TimWilliams

To open the VBProject
`Workbooks = Excel.Workbooks`
`Workbook=Workbooks.Open(file)`
`Workbook.VBProject`
but from this point I'm lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have allowed programmatical access to the VBA Project, I would suggest to write your macro to a text file (*.txt or *.bas) and then run the command that would import this text file has a VBA code module. For example:

```
DataFileName = 'D:\Test\DataFile.xlsm';
CodeFileName = 'D:\Test\CodeFile.txt';

Excel = actxserver('Excel.Application');
Workbooks = Excel.Workbooks;
Workbook=Workbooks.Open(DataFileName);

% Make Excel visible (Optional)
Excel.visible = 1;

%% Import the code
Import(Workbook.VBProject.VBComponents,CodeFileName);

%% Save
Excel.Application.DisplayAlerts = 0; %Avoid overwrite warning
SaveAs(Workbook,DataFileName);
Excel.Application.DisplayAlerts = 1;

%% Close Excel
Quit(Excel);
delete(Excel);
```

In this case, `CodeFile.txt` could look like this:

```
Attribute VB_Name = "ModuleName"
Option Explicit

Sub SomeMacro()

    Msgbox "From MATLAB, with love..."

End Sub
```

Here, the line `Attribute VB_Name = ...` is essential and will determine the name of the module. For `Option Explicit`, it is not mandatory, but it's [good practice](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html).