# Formula for plotting a graph in Excel

Tags: excel, matlab

I am using Matlab to write a table of values into Excel. I wanted to create a button in multiple cells, which will kind of do some calculations on the date present in other cells, and then plot a simple graph.

Is there a formula to do this.

For example,

I write some values into columns A and B.

I want to make a graph now, with A on x axis and B on y axis.

But with a simple formula, which can be written from Matlab to Excel in a text format.

thanks.

Comment: Excel doesn't create graphs using formulas. You create them manually through the user interface or can automate them using VBA.

Comment: hi @Michael, can I atleast change the date points in x and y axis automatically. with a formula?

Comment: Yes, formulas can be written in Excel to automatically update data through calculations. You question doesn't really specify what you want help with though.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want to create a button in your Excel file. If this is the case, this is more of an **VBA** question than matlab. You could probably ask your question with the VBA tag.

Once MATLAB writes your data to the excel file, you cannot manipulate the data (e.g. plotting) with MATLAB unless you read it again...

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will look into this post and see if I am able to do what I want. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48190180/can-matlab-write-a-macro-in-an-excel-file-via-activex